# Java EAR project containing multiple JARS

Tags: java, ant, jar, build, ear

I was assigned to work with ten year old legacy Java project. The code base is huge and it's my first encounter with big enterprise project.

I'm confused about the project structure, as there are dozens of *something.jar* called **directories** inside src/application.ear directory, each of these jar folders containing it's own ant build and configuration. Yet the final build will be single ear. Is the rationale for building jars from different subsystems to ship them to possibly integrated system? Is this some common pattern to name the folders by the jar names?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the rationale for building jars from different subsystems to ship them to possibly integrated system?

Yes,

> EAR (Enterprise ARchive) is a file format used by Java EE for packaging one or more modules into a single archive so that the deployment of the various modules onto an application server happens simultaneously and coherently.

In the J2EE world, an entreprise application can be composed of web modules, ejb modules, etc.

So (and this is me guessing), the directories called **something.jar** can be submodules of the enterprise application o library modules required by the application (EAR)...

> Is this some common pattern to name the folders by the jar names?

I don't really. I never had seen before. But I understand the purpose of such layout. The purpose is to encapsulate the files (build.xml -- ant tasks) that build some artefact called **something.jar** ("required by the EAR app, perhaps?"). So using this layout, a developer can easily identify which build file (build.xml) constructs what artefact. Also, using this layout, a developer can define a master build script that coordinates the order and execution of the other build scripts (EAR submodules).

So, in other words, you're watching a "pseudo" Maven framework, using ANT as implementation...

May be is time to start migrating this old application to the maven model!